# Custom Directions with Mapkit

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, directions

I was wondering if it is possible to create custom directions with mapkit. For example I want to create a map for my university which has roads but also has walking paths that apple doesn't have in there maps is it possible for me to create custom directions using mapkit? I know that I can do a tileoverlay so that it shows the walking path but is it possible for me to use the paths I create for directions?

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality isn't available in MapKit. You might look into a platform like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com) for being able to combine custom data in the map with custom data in the routing so that the two are 1) separate from the data that MapKit makes available) and 2) able to use custom data.